# Error in unzipping a file from a python script running as daemon

Tags: python, linux, unzip

I am getting an error whenever i try to run following  unzip command from a python script which is running as a daemon

Command :

> unzip abcd.zip > /dev/null

Error

```
End-of-central-directory signature not found$ a zip file, or it 
constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive. In the latter case
the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last 
disk(s) of this archive

unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of abcd.zip$
        abcd.zip.zip, and cannot find abcd.zip.ZIP, period.
```

Could anyone help me in this regard?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you run the command from the command line (the errors imply the zip file is invalid)

Comment: After a while the daemon itself getting hanged,i would like to know whether this error causing the daemon to hang ?

Comment: Which unzip is being used when you run as normal user? Which unzip is used when it is run as a daemon? Execute `os.system("which unzip")` in your python script and check the output for both cases.

Comment: I tried it ,both are same (/usr/bin/unzip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually that would mean exactly what it says: that the file `abcd.zip` is not a valid ZIP file. Are you able to `unzip abcd.zip` as a normal user? If not, it would seem to have become corrupted. How did you get hold of it? Check for newline-mangling operations like ASCII-mode FTP.

Can you read the file with the built-in Python [zipfile](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) module? Handling files directly in Python is generally preferable to kicking it out onto the command line.

Comment: i can able to unzip the same file as a normal user

Comment: I even tested the zip file with unzip -t option to verify it, but when i run that from python daemon i am getting this error for some files

Comment: i validated the file its not corrupted

Comment: After a while same files are getting unzipped successfully,i would like to know the reason why this error is getting displayed

Comment: There is no reason I can think of why some files would fail to unzip and then later succeed. Is it possible that the files are in the middle of being created, eg. that they're being downloaded from another server, so appear to be incomplete until the download is finished?

Comment: No its sure that all files are complete before they get unzipped

Answer (score 0):

Validate the file first. This looks like a corrupted/invalid zip file.

Comment: i validated the file its not corrupted